# Deadlock: Items needed to upgrade furnace need upgraded furnace to be crafted

Tags: starbound

As of now, following items are needed to upgrade Forge to Atomic Furnace (wiki is outdated on this):

[image]

I bought the battery at [Infinity Express](https://starbounder.org/Infinity_Express), however they do not sell copper wire.

So I'm pretty stuck right now. What can I do? I found few copper wires in my chest, but I don't know where they're from and if I accumulated 15 over whole gameplay, I doubt I can quickly get another ten...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copper wire, aside from being crafted at the Atomic Furnance you're trying to make, is a drop from the [Bobot](https://starbounder.org/Bobot), [Lumoth](https://starbounder.org/Lumoth), [Scandroid](https://starbounder.org/Scandroid), and [Triplod](https://starbounder.org/Triplod) enemies.